# tcsh script - Will not output simple ls -l command using cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin, tcsh

I want to check whether or not the files in a directory A match the files in directory B, and that these matched files are not modified/changed.

I am very new to this new programming environment as I am used to Windows. This task is a part of a school project but I am trying to run tcsh scripts on my Windows using cygwin and bash(?). However, i specify the tcsh environment in my scripts.

This simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
echo Hello world;

set listing=`ls -l`

echo $listing
```

Gives me the following output:

```
Shawn@Shawn-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/Shawn/Desktop
$ ./lab3.sh
Hello world
Unknown user: $372.
```

However, I am able to run the "ls -l" command directly into the command line and it returns the appropriate result, so I don't know why it can't execute my "ls -l" command in the script. I don't know if there something wrong with my tcsh syntax in the script and why it returns the error message "Unknown user: #372."

Comment: tcsh is a very poor shell for writing scripts, do you have to do it this way?

Comment: Does it work better if you quote the variable, `echo "$listing"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the development tool that we are required to use for assignments. No, I get the exact same output when i use echo "$listing"

Comment: Also, if i change listing to =`date` it outputs the date command perfectly. Why does it have a problem with ls?

Comment: There's probably a special character in the `ls -l` output. Try `set listing = "\`ls -l\`"`

Comment: Nope, then instead of the line Unknown user: $372., it writes 'ls- l'

Comment: It must be cygwin's issue because i just ran this script on my school's linux computer, after giving the script the appropriate permissions, it ran perfect with the expected ls -l output

Comment: @shawna: Probably because you didn't have a file with a `~` in its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file or directory whose name is something like `~372`, or that contains that as part of its name.

If you type

```
echo ~372
```

at the shell prompt, the shell will try to expand `~372` to the home directory of the user with the name `372`. Almost certainly there is no such user -- thus the error message.

Your command:

```
set listing=`ls -l`
```

isn't likely to be very useful anyway. The output of `ls -l`, which is line-oriented with aligned columns, will be joined into a single line of text with multiple blanks replaced by single blanks. It will be a mess, difficult to read. (Perhaps the point is to demonstrate this.)

You can avoid the error on `~372` by adding double quotes around the backticks:

```
set listing="`ls -l`"
```

But now the string `$listing` contains that troublesome `~372`, and if you try to `echo` it you'll have the same problem; `$listing` will expand to the string, and `echo` will try to expand the `~372` contained within it.

So you *also* need to add quotes (or a `:q` suffix`) to the`echo` command.

Here's what I got using tcsh on my system:

```
% touch foo bar '~372'
% ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 ~372
% set listing = `ls -l`
Unknown user: 372.
% set listing = "`ls -l`"
% echo $listing
Unknown user: 372.
% echo "$listing"
total 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 bar -rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 foo -rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 0 Sep 19 14:06 ~372
%
```

This is not a particularly useful thing to do, but that's how to do it.

Note that if you were using bash, then this:

```
listing="`ls -l`"
echo "$listing"
```

would preserve the multi-line formatting.

Obligatory link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to print to terminal, then this is all you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh

echo Hello world

ls -l
```

---

If you need to save it as an array or something it would be easier to output it to a text file and then read it in line by line as an array. (The spacing gets messed up for me to do it directly).

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh

echo Hello world

ls -l > output.txt
```

If this is what you need, read up on importing a text file as an array.

Also, this would be much easier in bash if you have the choice.